# Filtering with a predicate that takes 2 arguments

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

What I want would basically be a O(n^2) iteration over a list. Let's say I have a list of two integers,

```
let list = [2312, 8000, 3456, 7000, 1234]
```

and a function to check if adding two integers together would produce a result higher than 20000 (this could be an arbitrary function that takes two integers and returns a boolean).

```
myPredicate :: Int -> Int -> Bool
myPredicate x y = x + y > 10000
```

Is there a way to apply this predicate to the above list to get a list of lists that include valid pairs, like this:

```
>> filter myPredicate list
>> [[2312, 8000], [3456, 8000], [3456, 7000], [8000, 7000]]
```

Comment: Can we assume that `myPredicate x y` = `myPredicate y x` (asking since you say "this could be an arbitrary function that takes two integers and returns a boolean")?

Comment: @DavidYoung yes, in my case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to construct the list of pairs,

```
pairs xs = [(y,z) | (y:ys) <- tails xs, z <- ys]
```

and then filter it out using your predicate which needs to be in uncurried form,

```
myPredicate' :: (Int,Int) -> Bool
myPredicate' x y = x + y > 10000
```

so,

```
filter myPredicate' (pairs list)
```

or equivalently

```
filter (uncurry myPredicate) (pairs list)
```

Comment: ... or `[ [y,z] | (y:ys) <- tails xs, z <- ys, myPredicate' y z]`. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is supported by Haskell syntax directly.

```
[(x, y) | x <- myList, y <- myList, x + y > 20000]
```

This will return reversed and repeated pairs. If that's not what you need, consider these list comprehensions:

```
[(x, y) | x <- myList, y <- myList, x < y, x + y > 20000] -- no reversed pairs, no repeats

[(x, y) | x <- myList, y <- myList, x <= y, x + y > 20000] -- repeats, no reversed pairs
```

If for some reason unknown to science you have a list with duplicate elements, say `[30000,30000]` *and you want only elements at different positions to form valid pairs*, then this simple list comprehension won't work. I have no idea what kind of real life problem would require this, but here you are:

```
[(y,z) | (y:ys) <- tails xs, z <- ys, y + z > 20000]
```

(idea stolen from the other answer)

Comment: This will include reversals (`(2312, 8000)` and `(8000, 2312)`) as well as duplicates (`(8000, 8000)`), which the question seems to preclude.

Comment: @chepner the question seems to say nothing about this. What result would one expect if the input list is `[3000, 3000]` and why?

Comment: I'm simply going by the OP's example output.

Comment: @chepner I ignored the example and went with the question as worded. The example is inadequate because if doesn't explain what to do with `[3000, 3000]`. I should have mentioned this in the answer though.